# Matlab matrix operations without loops

Tags: matlab, loops, optimization, for-loop, matrix

I have an issue with a code performing some array operations. It is getting too slow, because I am using loops. I am trying for some time to optimize this code and to re-write it with less or without loops. Until now unsuccessfully. Can you please help me solve this:

```
YVal = 1:1:100000;
M_MAX = 1000;
N_MAX = 2000;
clear YTemp
tic
for M=1:1:M_MAX 
    for N = 1:1:N_MAX 
       YTemp(M,N) = sum(YVal (N+1:N+M)  ) - sum(YVal   (1:M)  );  
    end
end
```

For large `N_MAX` and `M_MAX` the execution time of these two loops is very high. How can I optimize this?

Thank you!

Comment: The most time-consuming part is growing `YTemp` inside the loop. Replace `clear YTemp` by `YTemp = zeros(M_MAX,N_MAX)`, and you'll see a very nice speed increase already.

Comment: @Jonas - a point well made! Can you please elaborate a bit on the importance of pre-allocation in Matlab and post it as another answer here - I will +1 you for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `YVal` is larger than `N_MAX+M_MAX`

```
sum1 = cumsum( YVal(1:(M_MAX+N_MAX)) ); % sum1(M) = sum(YVal(1:M))
```

If I'm not mistaken, then

```
sum( YVal( N+1:N+M ) ) = sum1( N + M ) - sum1( N )
```

And therefore

```
YTemp( M, N ) = sum1( N + M ) - sum1( N ) - sum1( M )
```

Using [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html)

```
[M N] = ndgrid( 1:M_MAX, 1:N_MAX );
YTemp = sum1( N + M ) - sum1( N ) - sum1( M );
```

Have I got it right?

**EDIT:**
Another go without `ndgrid`

```
sum1 = cumsum( YVal( 1 : (N_MAX+M_MAX) ) );
YTemp = bsxfun( @minus, ...
            bsxfun( @minus, ...
                sum1( bsxfun( @plus, 1:N_MAX, (1:M_MAX)' ) ) , sum1 ),...
                    sum1' );
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to speed it up a little by hoisting the invariant term out of the inner loop, e.g.

```
for M=1:1:M_MAX 
    sum2 = sum(YVal(1:M));
    for N = 1:1:N_MAX 
       YTemp(M,N) = sum(YVal(N+1:N+M)) - sum2;  
    end
end
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer.
Though, I would like to find out how can I make these operations without loops. I should be able to compute also vectors like:
YVal = rand (100000, 1)

Comment: I don't see any easy way to vectorize this loop, but someone more expert than me with MATLAB may be able to help in due course. In the mean time you could use the above hoisting optimisation to potentially save yourself some execution time until you get a better solution.